# debugging error on nullreference

Tags: c#, oracle, system, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

Debugging error on Nullreference

I get this error when debugging my program:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Code below is the one that throws the error and I totally have no idea how to fix it. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

```
return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: It's not totally obvious to me what language this is or what you're trying to do- if it's c#, consider adding that to the tags, if it's sql, you might mention that as well.  Also, have you checked to see if cmd>executeSccalar() is returning null?  If so, that would be a possible cause.

Comment: It is c#. Can you give me the proper code to test the value of executescalar?
Like this? return cmd.ExecuteScalar;

Comment: using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(OracleHelper.connINT_STRING))
   {
    cn.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@"select qty from qtyIDTab where qtyid = :qtyidt", cn))
    {
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OracleParameter hmlidParam = new OracleParameter("hml", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 16);
     qtyidtParam.Value=qtyidt;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(qtyidtParam);

                    return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
   }

Comment: I'm don't really speak C#, but can you inspect in a debugger or log it to console?

Comment: @user548682 please add the code to your question not in the comments, so the question will be clear and complete.

Comment: Could you change your query from `select qty from qtyIDTab where qtyid = :qtyidt` to `select count(*) from qtyIDTab where qtyid = :qtyidt` as a test?  If there's no exception you know the problem is in the query result (i.e. no rows returned), if there is, it's likely in the setup of the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two possibilities:

1. cmd is null;
2. cmd.ExecuteScalar() returns null.

You could add temporary variables to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your result set has no records in it?

According to the docs on SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Object
>   The first column of the first row in the result
>   set, or a **null reference** (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set
>   is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

If no records are returned, it evaluates to a null reference, which would be consistent with your result.

Comment: Can you use SQL Management Studio (or a similar tool) to verify that your result returns a row?  You might also consider posting your SQL if you're not sure how to construct a query such that you always get a result row.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I did try to query in database before I post this question. The result is not null from database. Need help.

Comment: Have you successfully used SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar elsewhere in your code?  Could you add how you're setting up the `cmd.commandText` to your question?